# Как добавить HTML страницу с кликабельной картинкой в подпись для электронной яндекс-почты?

Tags: html, css, email, яндекс-почта

Можно ли добавить в подпись для яндекс-почты, картинку, которая имеет несколько кликабельный ссылок?

Сама HTML-страничка выглядит вот так, но когда я пытаюсь добавить в подпись HTML-страницу, то остаётся только картинка без ссылок...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Картинка ссылка</title>
</head>

<img src="https://miroslavs.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/12.png"
    alt="" usemap="#Navigation">

<map name="Navigation">
    <area shape="rect" coords="10,10,70,70" href="https://yandex.ru/" alt="Red">
    <area shape="rect" coords="80,10,140,70" href="https://yandex.ru/" alt="Green">
    <area shape="rect" coords="10,80,70,140" href="https://yandex.ru/" alt="Blue">
    <area shape="rect" coords="80,80,140,140" href="https://yandex.ru/" alt="Yellow">
</map>

</html>
```

Подскажите можно ли это исправить?

Comment: Я чего-то не понимаю или для ссылки по картинке, вы должны использовать тег <a href="ссыль">блок с картинкой</a> в html?

Comment: Да, но тогда будет жосткая привязка 1 изображение=1 ссылка, а если необходимо сделать несколько ссылок на одном изображении?

Comment: вы можете разделить картинку на несколько частей, и вставить на кажду ссылку. В стилях убрать все отступы. Еще вариант - редирект. Вы делаете ссылку с картинки на одну страницу, когда пользователь перейдет на неё, то вы можете перенаправить его на свои страницы.

Comment: Задача стоит в том, чтобы была одна картинка, а не множество.

Comment: скорее всего вам подойдет [это](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2015/02/several-references-in-the-picture.html?ysclid=l341msk0yu). В том сообщении, в комментариях, также указана ссылка, как сделать переход на несколько вкладок с картинке. Еще вариант имеется [такой](https://qna.habr.com/q/344386?ysclid=l341nh1u5k), но он немного схож с моим. Еще [один](https://abcinblog.blogspot.com/2016/05/kak-sdelat-dve-i-bolee-ssylok-s-odnoy.html) подобный вариант. Из всеъ этих вариантов, я как понял, нужно использовать [<map>](http://htmlbook.ru/html/map?ysclid=l341w43zyb)